# Dismissing custom UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios

I am loading a UIImagePickerController in this way:

```
- (void) launchCamera {

// Set up the camera
CustomCamera *cameraController = [[CustomCamera alloc] init];
cameraController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
cameraController.delegate = self;

cameraController.showsCameraControls = NO;
cameraController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
cameraController.toolbarHidden = YES;

// overlay on top of camera lens view
UIImageView *cameraOverlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_overlay.png"]];
cameraOverlayView.alpha = 0.0f;
cameraController.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlayView;

// animate the fade in after the shutter opens
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:2.2f];
cameraOverlayView.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];

[self presentModalViewController:cameraController animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to dismiss it. When I try

```
[cameraController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
```

I get a red error. The cameraController is just a UIImagePickerController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the cameraController did not do a presentation, the self object did. You are calling self present instead of cameraController

Comment: The error at  [cameraController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; has vanished by doing [cameraController presentModalViewController:cameraController animated:YES];. but still the controller is not removed from the screen